# How to use PowerShell to lookup DNS information?

Tags: powershell, dns

I want to automate the process of querying DNS records with PowerShell;

As I am behind the GFW I need dozens of IP addresses for each website so the odds of some of the addresses not being blocked is larger.

I found a website: [www.robtex.com](http://www.robtex.com) that suites my needs, it returns a large number of IP addresses, however its free API is limited: https://freeapi.robtex.com/pdns/forward/$webaddr, and using the webpage in web browsers is contrary to the purpose of automation;

How can I solve it?

---

Yeah, I am blocked from asking questions so I am now editing all my questions, if you think I have improved please don't hesitate to upvote, if not, feel free to leave a comment!

Comment: Okay so I have an idea, use useragents and cookies to make powershell masquerade as a browser, send https requests to server, put things in the input field, then retrieve responces and parse information, however I don't know the code yet, it shouldn't be hard to implement, will anyone help me before I post the answer myself again? I can't write complex codes first, but if I see the code (not assembly or machine code or hex) I will be able to comprehend it instantly and write similar codes.

Comment: That's a roundabout way of doing it, i'd look into solving your API problems instead. What is it that's limiting you to only a handful of IP addresses using the API?

Comment: Please visit the website and see by yourself, it is stated in the website, the free api is limited, it's a trimmed down version, the premium api functions better, but that'll cost money, I have no money and premium is not an option.

Comment: How many requests do you need to do daily/monthly? There could be another API that might fit.

Comment: Eg. this site seems to be offering 500 requests per month in the free plan: https://dns-lookup.whoisxmlapi.com/api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved it.

I PowerShell 7, my solution needs the HTML parser library PowerHTML to work;

- To install it, type the following in PowerShell:

  ```
  Install-Module -Name PowerHTML
  ```

It offers ConvertFrom-Html cmdlet, whose output is HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode object.

- The code:

  ```
  $Website = $Args
  $IPv4 = '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'
  $IPv6 = '([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}\:)(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?\:){1,6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}'
  $html = ConvertFrom-Html -uri "https://www.robtex.com/dns-lookup/$Website"
  $IP=@()
  $html.SelectNodes('//table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a').InnerText | Where {$_ -match "$IPv4|$IPv6"} | %{if ($IP -notcontains $_) {$IP+=$_}}
  $html.SelectNodes('//table/tbody/tr/td/a').InnerText | Where {$_ -match "$IPv4|$IPv6"} | %{if ($IP -notcontains $_) {$IP+=$_}}
  $html.SelectNodes('//p/a').InnerText | Where {$_ -match "$IPv4|$IPv6"} | %{if ($IP -notcontains $_) {$IP+=$_}}
  $IP >"$PSScriptRoot\${Website}_IP.txt"
  ```

Save as `DNSQuery.ps1`, usage example:

```
.\DNSQuery.ps1 "www.google.com"
```

Comment: does nothing...